# How to disable JSON format and send only the log message to Cloudwatch with Fluentbit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, filter, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, fluent-bit, firelens

I am trying to setup Firelens for my Fargate tasks. I would like to send logs to multiple locations, Cloudwatch and Elasticsearch.

But only to Cloudwatch I want to disable JSON format and send only the log message as it is.

I have the below configuration for Cloudwatch output.

```
[OUTPUT]
    Name cloudwatch
    Match *
    auto_create_group true
    log_group_name /aws/ecs/containerinsights/$(ecs_cluster)/application
    log_stream_name $(ecs_task_id)
    region eu-west-1
```

Currently logs are coming like this,

```
{
    "container_id": "1234567890",
    "container_name": "app",
    "log": "2021/08/10 18:42:49 [notice] 1#1: exit",
    "source": "stderr"
}
```

I want only the line,

```
2021/08/10 18:42:49 [notice] 1#1: exit
```

in Cloudwatch.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue using just CloudWatch where everything was wrapped in JSON - I imagine it'll be the same when using several targets.

The solution was to add the following to the `output` section:

```
   log_key log
```

This tells Fluent Bit to *only* include the data in the `log` key when sending to CloudWatch.

The [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/fargate-logging.html) have since been updated to include that line by default in [this PR](https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-eks-user-guide/pull/473/files).